# jQuery sliders setOpacity of individual OL layers while keeping a max cumulative total

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, openlayers, jquery-ui-slider

There are many examples of using the jQuery sliders and running a maximum cumulative total. However, I have been unsuccessful in drafting a version that will work with my application. I need to be able to set individual opacities of 6 openlayers layers, using the jQuery sliders, while never exceeding a cumulative total of 100 slider units.

---

### **Updated**

Here is how I am currently implementing it. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to go about code refactoring so that I reduce code duplication...

```
var sliders = $("#sliders .slider");

sliders.each(function() {
var value = parseInt($(this).text()),
    availableTotal = 100;

$(function() {
    $("#one").slider({
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        value: 20,
        slide: function(event, ui) {

            // Get current total
            var total = ui.value;

            sliders.not(this).each(function() {
                total += $(this).slider("option", "value");
            });
            if (total > availableTotal) {
                return false;
            }
            hii_1.setOpacity(ui.value / 100);
            // Update display to current value
            $(this).siblings().text(ui.value);
        }
    });
    $("#two").slider({
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        value: 20,
        slide: function(event, ui) {

            // Get current total
            var total = ui.value;

            sliders.not(this).each(function() {
                total += $(this).slider("option", "value");
            });
            if (total > availableTotal) {
                return false;
            }
            hii_2.setOpacity(ui.value / 100);
            // Update display to current value
            $(this).siblings().text(ui.value);
        }
    });
    $("#three").slider({
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        value: 20,
        slide: function(event, ui) {

            // Get current total
            var total = ui.value;

            sliders.not(this).each(function() {
                total += $(this).slider("option", "value");
            });
            if (total > availableTotal) {
                return false;
            }
            hii_3.setOpacity(ui.value / 100);
            // Update display to current value
            $(this).siblings().text(ui.value);
        }
    });
    $("#four").slider({
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        value: 16,
        slide: function(event, ui) {

            // Get current total
            var total = ui.value;

            sliders.not(this).each(function() {
                total += $(this).slider("option", "value");
            });
            if (total > availableTotal) {
                return false;
            }
            hii_4.setOpacity(ui.value / 100);
            // Update display to current value
            $(this).siblings().text(ui.value);
        }
    });
    $("#five").slider({
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        value: 16,
        slide: function(event, ui) {

            // Get current total
            var total = ui.value;

            sliders.not(this).each(function() {
                total += $(this).slider("option", "value");
            });
            if (total > availableTotal) {
                return false;
            }
            hii_5.setOpacity(ui.value / 100);
            // Update display to current value
            $(this).siblings().text(ui.value);
        }
    });
    $("#six").slider({
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        value: 8,
        slide: function(event, ui) {

            // Get current total
            var total = ui.value;

            sliders.not(this).each(function() {
                total += $(this).slider("option", "value");
            });
            if (total > availableTotal) {
                return false;
            }
            hii_6.setOpacity(ui.value / 100);
            // Update display to current value
            $(this).siblings().text(ui.value);
        }
    });
});
});
```

---

### **Original**

> The example I am most familiar with is posted here and below
>   http://jsfiddle.net/markieta/cWyQ3/
>
> ```
> var sliders = $("#sliders .slider");
> sliders.each(function() {
>     var value = parseInt($(this).text()),
>         availableTotal = 100;
>     $(this).empty().slider({
>         value: 0,
>         min: 0,
>         max: 100,
>         range: "min",
>         animate: true,
>         slide: function(event, ui) {
>             // Update display to current value
>             $(this).siblings().text(ui.value);
>             // Get current total
>             var total = 0;
>             sliders.not(this).each(function() {
>                 total += $(this).slider("option", "value");
>             });
>             // Need to do this because apparently jQ UI
>             // does not update value until this event completes
>             total += ui.value;
>             var max = availableTotal - total;
>             // Update each slider
>             sliders.not(this).each(function() {
>                 var t = $(this),
>                     value = t.slider("option", "value");
>                 t.slider("option", "max", max + value).siblings().text(value);
>                 t.slider('value', value);
>             });
>         }
>     });
> });
> ```
>
> Originally, I was setting the OpenLayers layer opacity using the
>   setOpacity method during the slide event of each unique slider.
>   However, I could not figure out how to keep a running total with this
>   method so as my sliders would not exceed 100 cumulative units.
>
> ```
> $(function() {
>     $( "#slider1" ).slider({
>     range: "min",
>     min: 0,
>     value: opacities[0],
>     slide: function(e, ui) {
>         hii_1.setOpacity(ui.value / 100);
>         $( "#amount1" ).val( ui.value );
>         }
>     });
>     $("#amount1" ).val($( "#slider1" ).slider( "value" ) );
> });
> ```
>
> ** x6 sliders **
>
> Any insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the [`slide` callback returns `false`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#event-slide) then the thumb won't move:

> Return false in order to prevent a slide, based on `ui.value`.

So all you need to do is grab the total values of the other sliders, add the new value of the current slider, and return `false` if it is too high:

```
slide: function(event, ui) {
    var total = ui.value;
    // sliders is all the sliders, we skip `this` because
    // we need to get the current value from ui.value as
    // above.
    sliders.not(this).each(function() {
        total += $(this).slider("option", "value");
    });
    if(total > availableTotal) // availableTotal is your max across all sliders
        return false;
    //...
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/QWYzm/